# Problemas con el cache

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, qrcode

Tengo un generador de codigo QR obtenido de una libreria de php y lo he integrado a la web donde quiero que se genere con un link concatenado con una variable de retorno de una query.... el tema es; que me genera una imagen "pero", si me logueo con otro usuario la imagen no se actualiza si no que queda en el cache la del usuario anterior....

el php de inicio de pagina:

```
<?php include("../getR.php"); 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuarios'])) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$iduser = $_SESSION['id_usuarios'];
$sql = " SELECT idusuarios, nombre FROM UsrCtrl01 WHERE idusuarios='$iduser'";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

$content="https://link/regref.php?referido=".utf8_decode($row['idusuarios']);

QRcode::png(
    $content
    ,"NombreArchivoQR.png"
    ,QR_ECLEVEL_Q
    ,15
    ,2 
);
?>
```

como lo integro en el HTML

```
<button class="button-label" onClick="GenerarQR()" id="show" style="cursor: pointer">Generar QR</button>
            <br><br>
            <span>
            <a download="NombreArchivoQR.png" href="NombreArchivoQR.png"><img src="NombreArchivoQR.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; align-content: center"/></a>
            </span>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("img").hide();
                });
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#show").click(function(){
                $("img").show();
                });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con cache, he batallado mucho con código, pero le mando atributos al `src` a manera de forzar al navegador a buscar el componente

```
<a download="NombreArchivoQR.png?sample<?= md5(time()); ?>" href="NombreArchivoQR.png?sample<?= md5(time()); ?>"><img src="NombreArchivoQR.png?sample<?= md5(time()); ?>" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; align-content: center"/></a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha solucionado mi problema de momento pero es robusto, veamos si alguien tiene algun llamado al codigo de otra manera para mantener la estructura mas ordenada (un par de dias), si no, le doy el punto a tu solucion